# does .slideUp apply display:none to the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example :

```
$('element').slideUp();

if('element').css('display')!='none'){
// do something
}
```

The if condition returns true or false ?

Comment: Idk if your question is a typo or not... but as it stands, that would create an exception because strings don't have a `css` method.

Comment: @NormanBreau  I mean any element it could be 'div' , 'p' or whatever

Comment: @Euphoria Yes ! and it returned TRUE which is not supposed to be !

Comment: do you mean `if ( $('element').css('display')`?

Comment: @BishoyEssam
Try to use `if($('#element').is(':visible'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) executes asynchronously, so you need to check the condition inside the complete callback - which is really not required because when the callback is called the element will be hidden.

So you can do what ever you want to do after the slideUp in the complete callback handler without checking the condition

```
$('element').slideUp(function () {
    // if($(this).is(':visible'))
    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {//really not needed
        // do something
    }
});
```

Also to check whether an element is visible, you can use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check it's hidden or not by using one of above ways, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YHJ9A/121/) is demo

```js
var test = $('#test'),
    btnTest = $('#btnTest'),
    up = $('#up');


btnTest.click(function() {
    if(!$('#test').is(":visible")){
  alert('ok');
 }
});
    
up.click(function() {
    test.slideUp(1000, function() {
        alert('complete');
    });
});
```

```css
#test {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: thin solid gray;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="btnTest">Test Hidden</button>
<button id="up">slideUp()</button>

<div id="test">
    Aliquam quis tortor diam dis, mid augue est magnis in pid montes. Est urna penatibus et facilisis in, dictumst nec ac duis odio mauris? Purus mus montes non aenean placerat tempor mus? Tincidunt aliquet nunc tristique tristique augue adipiscing natoque urna sit natoque in? Non elit? Duis eros porta amet scelerisque odio natoque natoque!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)